# invert window preserving hue

Tags: compiz, brightness

I love the invert window color feature in compiz, however I would love to be able to invert just the brightness, preserving the original hue. What I'd like even more would be a global feature across all windows that will brightness invert the window, and if that is darker than the original, use that, otherwise use the original. Then I never would have to look at a white screen again ;).

update:

I think making this change to the shader in `neg.cpp` *might* do the basic version of what I want. I found rgb to hsv to rgb GLSL code, injected this into the original shader, set the `v` to `1.0 - v` (I'm assuming the range for `value` is 1.0, but I'm not sure), then convert the result back to rgb and use it as the final pixel color:

```
/* rgb:hsv conversion based on:
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095909/from-rgb-to-hsv-in-opengl-glsl */
static std::string fragment_function = "                                         \n\
void neg_fragment () {                                                           \n\
    // convert to hsv                                                            \n\
    vec4 K = vec4(0.0, -1.0 / 3.0, 2.0 / 3.0, -1.0);                             \n\
    vec4 p = mix(vec4(c.bg, K.wz), vec4(c.gb, K.xy), step(c.b, c.g));            \n\
    vec4 q = mix(vec4(p.xyw, c.r), vec4(c.r, p.yzx), step(p.x, c.r));            \n\
    float d = q.x - min(q.w, q.y);                                               \n\
    float e = 1.0e-10;                                                           \n\
    vec3 c = vec3(abs(q.z + (q.w - q.y) / (6.0 * d + e)), d / (q.x + e), q.x);   \n\
    // flip luminosity (value)                                                   \n\
    c.z = 1.0 - c.z                                                              \n\
    // convert back to rgb                                                       \n\
    K = vec4(1.0, 2.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 3.0);                                    \n\
    p = abs(fract(c.xxx + K.xyz) * 6.0 - K.www);                                 \n\
    c = c.z * mix(K.xxx, clamp(p - K.xxx, 0.0, 1.0), c.y);                       \n\
    // use converted rgb value                                                   \n\
    gl_FragColor = vec4(c, gl_FragColor.a);                                      \n\
}                                                                                \n\
";
```

I found the compiz repository on bazaar. Will browse the source code and try to find where the invert color module is implemented

For anyone wondering, the plugin is the "negative" or "neg" plugin, and the relevant part of the source code is [here on bazaar.launchpad.net](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~compiz-team/compiz/0.9.13/files/head:/)

All three contact email addresses on the original readme for the plugin have gone dark - if anyone has a way of contacting the original developer that would be greatly appreciated.

I don't have much more time to put into this but if anyone figures out a way to get compiz to compile and can test this I would appreciate it!